# How to make some similar looking races different?

Tags: fantasy-races

So currently I'm working on a fantasy universe, it massive with at right now 45 main races/factions and several dozen minor. I've been able to make all of them unique in style, look, and what they are known for. But currently I have 2 races that are similar in look, dameons, and flesh archons look similar but are completely different in style,

Flesh archons: The flesh archons are neither male nor female though they can have some of their characteristics. originally created by the Plague cult to be a slave force and a testing species for their diseases. The plague cult would create the flesh archons and then forcefully change them to have the characteristics of other races to test plagues. Pale white flesh, variation in looks. Humanoid, can have natural armor. They are blind so they required an advanced form of echolocation that is released at a subsonic frequency to find anything.  Since they are neither male or female they reproduce through a form of osmosis where one flesh archon can split in  two. That flesh archon that splits will still live. A flesh archon could never split/reproduce  growing incredibly large. Their are different subspecies of the flesh archon that require those of that same subspecies to create. Each subspecies is the result of the plague cult forcefully manipulation the genetics of the flesh archons to take on the  characteristics of other races to test plagues that were engineered to affect them. The forceful manipulation and the diseases changed the flesh archons to look far from their original looks.  The flesh archons respect nature but not so much that they will glorify it to a higher elevation than themselves they are very unindustrial 
 And pirimative.
Colors:white, some grey

Dameon: creatures from another realm called the endless pit. The only way to for them to come to Aphila is by possessing another body the instant they come through. When they possess the other body it is completely transformed into a new creature usually a monserious one. The Dameon cannot caste magic but the Dameon’s do put off an Arua called plariz that will cause  madness, hulutionate, or fear when given long term exposure. Short term exposure will only affect the weak minded causing fear and lost of willpower.  The plariz has a different effect on other dameons, the dameon who has the stronger arua will bind the weaker dameons to their will. This bond can only be broken by if the leader dies. They do not require to eat, breath, or even age.They also can have a range of racial abilities that are given once they create their new body. The power of these racial abilities can vary between each Dameon who each his variation of power that has randomly appeared in them with no real explanation. ( it is not common knowledge that the power is actually the power of the god leviathan malog that has been siphoned off to different dameons that his spirit likes.)When every they possess a creature runes and symbols are imprinted on the creatures flesh by various means, scars, burns, open cuts, Ect . These symbols are the effect of the Dameon possessing another creature and whenever a Dameon is bound to another Dameon the symbols rearrange into a new symbol similar but not exactly the same as the stronger Dameon.

They do not build or invent only relying on their racial abilities and mutation for combat ( some racial abilities might be magic in nature.

So is it enough that these two factions are systematically different but have similar looks, or do I need to ax one of them?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm also new. Please not that you have to request access to your google doc dameon (daemon?) description

Comment: As long as you have a clear visual distinction its okay for them to look similar. Think of elves and humans. Its basically the pointy ears. Its just that you need to develop their cultures differently.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  For the record, that is one whomping long question - and that's pretty much always bad.  You have words, references, titles, that don't even lead to info useful to the question (e.g., "Chaozon:..."). Considering two hugely popular species in Star Trek are Vulcans and Romulans - and they basically differ only in one's choice to adopt logic - I would vote that you're OK.  Cheers.

Comment: sorry first time, will do better next time, just wanted to get across what i was trying for

Comment: @Sparkwarrior777 - all the detail that you have added about your other creations shows your passion, but is not really necessary to answer your question.  I am afraid it will put off people who do not want to wade thru all that detail.  Your original was fine.

Comment: Hi @Sparkwarrior777 -- TLDR. Walls of text are great on wikis and websites dedicated to your worldbuilding. Please do some serious whackage on this query! It's actually spot on for this kind of forum, but, in to misquote Emperor Joseph, there are simply too many words.

Answer (score 4):

**It is great that they look the same.**

It can be a running gag that one type is mistaken for the other, and vice versa.  Even members of each type have trouble telling what exactly an individual is.  You can have some boss require that the flesh archons wear orange pinneys to tell them apart.  The archons demand that the daemons wear pinneys too because otherwise it is not fair.  Other fantasy races make fun of their pinneys, or wear silly pinneys of their own top tease them, and so the daemons and flesh archons tear up the pinneys and they are back to square 1.   The two wind up hating each other but they can't really fight because they can't tell which side others are on and they wind up fighting with others of their own kind.

It could be revealed that they actually are the same thing.  That makes each group even madder and they go back to the pinneys for a while.

Somehow I feel like your universe could use a little humor.  This could work!